# Contrapositive of logical statement with 2 conditionals

Tags: logic

I'm not familiar with formalising mathematical logic, but I want to know what is the correct way to state the contrapositive of a statement of the structure: If $A$ and $B$, then $C$. I suppose it is: If not $C$, then we can't have $A$ and $B$ simultaneously.
But in this particular case, B and C seems to be "tied together".

Fermat’s Theorem: If real function $f$ has a local maximum or minimum at $c$, and if $f'$ exists at $c$, then $f'(c)=0$.

I had 2 possible ways of defining the contrapositive.

1. If $f'(c)\neq 0$, then $f$ doesn't have a local maxima/minima at $c$. (since stating $f'(c)\neq 0$ actually implies the differentiability of $f$ at $c$)
2. If we don't have $f'(c)=0$, then if $f$ has a local maxima/minima at $c$, $f'(c)$ is undefined, or if $f'(c)$ is defined, then $f$ doesn't have a local maxima/minima at $c$.

The problem with the 1st way is that I'm not just negating $C$, I'm also claiming that condition $B$ holds.
The problem with the 2nd way is that the statement "we don't have $f'(c)=0$" seems somewhat vague.
I welcome answers with logical symbols, but hopefully they can be explained in words as well.

Comment: Perhaps include your own work using a truth table?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with truth tables. Is it 3 dimensional in this case?

Comment: A truth table with 3 variables will have $2^3 = 8$ rows. Also note. "not (A and B)" is "not A or not B".

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 What are the headers of the truth table in this case? Actually it doesn't seem C should be a variable.

Comment: @JiaChengSun - would you say "Q should be a variable" in "If P then Q"? (The headers would be A B C A^B (A^B)->C, at the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your statements as
$A$:  $f$ has local max/min at $c$
$B$:  $f'$ exists at $c$
$C$:  $f'(c)=0$.

The contraposition of $$A\wedge B\implies C$$ is $$\neg C\implies\neg(A\wedge B).$$  This can be written as $$\neg C\implies \neg A\vee\neg B$$ since either $A$ or $B$ being false will cause $A\wedge B$ to be false.

Therefore, your negative statements will be
$A$:  $f$ does not have local max/min at $c$
$B$:  $f'$ does not exist at $c$
$C$:  $f'(c)\neq0$.

Back into English, we have:

"If $f'(c)\neq0$, then either $f$ does not have a local max/min at $c$, or $f'$ does not exist at $c$, or both."

Comment: So, what I understand from this is that $f'(c)\neq 0$ doesn't automatically imply the existence of $f'(c)$.

Comment: This motivates me to ask if the following inequation is valid. $A\neq B$, $A$ being a matrix, $B$ being a real number. I suppose this is most definitely a yes.

Comment: Correct.  If it does not equal $0$, it could be undefined.

Comment: $f'(c)$ could take one of three states:  1.  $f'(c)=0$, 2.  $f'(c)\neq0$, or 3.  $f'(c)$ is undefined.    Both (1) and (3) being true automatically nullifies the other two, but (2) being true only nullifies (1) and _not necessarily_ (3).

Comment: It is very important to carefully define your variables.  Obviously a matrix is not equal to a real number since they are different constructs.  But the question to be asked at that point is whether that inequation has any real meaning.